# ゴミPCを集めて任意のプログラムを動かしたい

Tags: linux, windows, macos

## やりたいこと

ゴミPC(RAMが4GB、CPUがCeleronなど)を集めて、ひとつの高性能なPCのように扱いたい。
例えば4台のマシンを使ってPhotoshopをサクサク動かせる環境を整えたい。

## 現状

上記目標を達成するにはHPCという分野の技術が使えそうだと検討を付けたのですが、
調べても科学技術計算関連の話題しかなく困っています。

## 教えて欲しいこと

Windowsやmacで動くような一般的なソフトウェアを、複数のPCを束ねた仮想PC上で動作させるには
どのような手段があるのでしょうか？例えば使用するアプリの名前や、プロトコルの名前などがあれば
先に進めるのですが。

Comment: いわゆる「グリッドコンピューティング (または分散コンピューティング)」等の技術が該当しそうですが、気軽に使えるものがあるのかまでは分かりません。 / HPC はどちらかというと「リソースを無駄なく使う」イメージで、今回のようにリソースを束ねて使うとはやや異なるのかなと。

Comment: ありがとうございます。Globus Toolkitというグリッドコンピューティングのためのツールを見つけたのですが、2018年に公開自体が止まっているようですね。Sun Grid Engineの後継PJも2016年から開発が停止しているようですし、現在アクティブなプロジェクトは存在しないのでしょうか・・・。

Comment: 既存のものを実行モジュールに手を加えずに分散対応にしたいのか、ソースコードに手を加えて分散対応にするのか、についていまいち掴みきれないまま回答してしまいましたが、質問の意図は新規のソースコードを(または既存のソースコードに手を加えて)分散対応したいということで合ってますか？

Comment: いえ、既存ソースには手を加えずにできないかと考えていました。どうやら難しいようですね。。

Answer (score 2):

> Windowsやmacで動くような一般的なソフトウェアを、複数のPCを束ねた仮想PC上で動作させる

既存の分散処理に非対応なソフトに何も手を加えること無く、制約なく複数PCで分散実行させるということであれば困難だと思います。
(例えばVirtualBoxのような仮想マシンソフトでスレッドの処理を別マシンに分散させるようなものとか、この世に無いとは断言は出来ませんが…)

ただ分散処理に対応したソフトウェアという意味であればそのようなソフトはあったと思います。画像/映像分野でレイトレーシングとか3Dモデリングとかレンダリングとかのソフトではそういう分散実行機能を持つようなものがあったような気はします。(PhotoShopはどうなのかは知りません)

以下、自分で分散実行処理を作り出すということであれば、キーワード的なものを挙げると次のようなものが思いつきました。(最近のものは挙げることが出来ていないと思います)

- MPI(同一アーキテクチャの複数マシンの複数プロセス間でメッセージ通信するプロトコルとそのプログラム実装)
- PVM(MPIと同様の仕組みだが、複数アーキテクチャのスペックの違うマシンをかき集めて使うことが出来る)
- distcc(コンパイルを複数マシンで分散して行うCコンパイラのフロントエンド)

Comment: ありがとうございます。頂いたキーワードでググってみたら、「network renderingという技術が存在する」ということまでは分かりました。今やろうとしていることは、ソフト側の対応がないと難しいのですね。。グリッドコンピューティングに関するOSSも開発終了しているようですし、自分で作るしかないのかもしれません。。